# Rewrite URL in wordpress child theme

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm  making a wordpress child theme as an app. I would like to make a rewrite of an URL in the theme, since it's sometimes more seo friendly.

If someone enters for example
www.domain.com/show-new-cars/

I would like the server to load
www.domain.com/index.php?loadcars=1

I tried to put this in the child theme folders  functions.php  without any results.

```
 add_action( 'init', 'wpse7379_init' );
function wpse7379_init()
{
add_rewrite_rule('show-new-cars/',
'index.php?loadcars=1',
'top');
}
```

Comment: Did you flush your rewrite rules?  Try saving a permalink structure to get them to flush.

Comment: Yep, that seemed to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); does the trick.

This is an update due to not using flush every time the page loads, since it can increase server load allot.

```
//When activated trough admin
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == 'themes.php' ) {

    add_action( 'init', 'wpse7379_init' );
    function wpse7379_init()
    {
    add_rewrite_rule('show-new-cars/',
    'index.php?loadcars=1',
    'top');
    }
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

}
```

Comment: One thing with this approach, flushing rules on every page load increases overhead.  The standard approach is to either flush the rules in a plugin installer callback, or to check to see if the rule exists when adding a route from a theme.

Comment: Added code so its runned only when activating theme via admin, thanks for feedback